# Pandas Cumcount() over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, running-count

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data = {'exercise': ['squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench'],
        'session': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'weight': [100, 100, 120, 120, 80, 80, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 80, 90, 100, 110],
        'velocity': [0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = data.keys())

print(df)
```

```
   exercise  session  weight  velocity
0     squat        0     100      0.30
1     squat        0     100      0.25
2     squat        0     120      0.20
3     squat        0     120      0.15
4     bench        0      80      0.30
5     bench        0      80      0.25
6     bench        0     100      0.20
7     bench        0     110      0.15
8     squat        1     120      0.30
9     squat        1     130      0.25
10    squat        1     140      0.20
11    squat        1     150      0.15
12    bench        1      80      0.30
13    bench        1      90      0.25
14    bench        1     100      0.20
15    bench        1     110      0.15
```

What I want to do is to add two columns, one for set number and one for rep number.
Set number should increase by 1 for each weight change exercise & session is the same, else reset to 0.

Rep number should increase by 1 for each velocity change if exercise, session & weight is the same, else reset to 0.

> The logic I wrote above was flawed. What I meant was that the set number should increase for each change in weight (per line), but reset to 0 if either exercise or session changes.
>
> Rep count should then be the number of lines in each set.

Like this:

```
data = {'exercise': ['squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench'],
        'session': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'weight': [100, 100, 120, 120, 80, 80, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 80, 90, 100, 110],
        'velocity': [0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15],
        'set': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
        'rep': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = data.keys())
print(df)
```

```
   exercise  session  weight  velocity  set  rep
0     squat        0     100      0.30    0    0
1     squat        0     100      0.25    0    1
2     squat        0     120      0.20    1    0
3     squat        0     120      0.15    1    1
4     bench        0      80      0.30    0    0
5     bench        0      80      0.25    0    1
6     bench        0     100      0.20    1    0
7     bench        0     110      0.15    2    0
8     squat        1     120      0.30    0    0
9     squat        1     130      0.25    1    0
10    squat        1     140      0.20    2    0
11    squat        1     150      0.15    3    0
12    bench        1      80      0.30    0    0
13    bench        1      90      0.25    1    0
14    bench        1     100      0.20    2    0
15    bench        1     110      0.15    3    0
```

I think this should be possible using groupby and cumcount, but I struggle to make it work.

Comment: Is line `7` correct?

Comment: It's look like the expected output line `7` is wrong. 'set` value in line 7 should equal `2` as the desired behavior described in the question.

Comment: I mistyped, line 7 the weight should have been 100. But given that it was set to 110 the set, rep should be 2, 0. I’ll have this updated when I have more time ☺️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting a bit, I ended up using this solution:

```
df['set_'] = df.groupby(['exercise', 'session'])['weight'].apply(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).cumsum() - 1)
df['rep_'] = df.groupby(['exercise', 'session', 'set_']).cumcount()
```

It works as expected for the posted example and in my real dataset with much more data and more scenarios.

```
data = {'exercise': ['squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench'],
        'session': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'weight': [100, 100, 120, 120, 80, 80, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 80, 90, 100, 110],
        'velocity': [0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15],
        'set': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
        'rep': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = data.keys())

df['set_'] = df.groupby(['exercise', 'session'])['weight'].apply(lambda x: (x != x.shift()).cumsum() - 1)
df['rep_'] = df.groupby(['exercise', 'session', 'set_']).cumcount()
df['as_expected'] = (df['set_'] == df['set']) & (df['rep_'] == df['rep'])

print(df)
```

```
   exercise  session  weight  velocity  set  rep  set_  rep_  as_expected
0     squat        0     100      0.30    0    0     0     0         True
1     squat        0     100      0.25    0    1     0     1         True
2     squat        0     120      0.20    1    0     1     0         True
3     squat        0     120      0.15    1    1     1     1         True
4     bench        0      80      0.30    0    0     0     0         True
5     bench        0      80      0.25    0    1     0     1         True
6     bench        0     100      0.20    1    0     1     0         True
7     bench        0     110      0.15    2    0     2     0         True
8     squat        1     120      0.30    0    0     0     0         True
9     squat        1     130      0.25    1    0     1     0         True
10    squat        1     140      0.20    2    0     2     0         True
11    squat        1     150      0.15    3    0     3     0         True
12    bench        1      80      0.30    0    0     0     0         True
13    bench        1      90      0.25    1    0     1     0         True
14    bench        1     100      0.20    2    0     2     0         True
15    bench        1     110      0.15    3    0     3     0         True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) and [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['set1'] = (df.groupby(['exercise','session'])['weight']
                .transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]))
df['rep1'] = df.groupby(['exercise','session','weight']).cumcount()
print (df)
   exercise  session  weight  velocity  set  rep  set1  rep1
0     squat        0     100      0.30    0    0     0     0
1     squat        0     100      0.25    0    1     0     1
2     squat        0     120      0.20    1    0     1     0
3     squat        0     120      0.15    1    1     1     1
4     bench        0      80      0.30    0    0     0     0
5     bench        0      80      0.25    0    1     0     1
6     bench        0     100      0.20    1    0     1     0
7     bench        0     110      0.15    1    1     2     0
8     squat        1     120      0.30    0    0     0     0
9     squat        1     130      0.25    1    0     1     0
10    squat        1     140      0.20    2    0     2     0
11    squat        1     150      0.15    3    0     3     0
12    bench        1      80      0.30    0    0     0     0
13    bench        1      90      0.25    1    0     1     0
14    bench        1     100      0.20    2    0     2     0
15    bench        1     110      0.15    3    0     3     0
```

Comment: @antoine - I try understand line `7` and failed, I guess output is wrong.

Comment: yes, `7     bench        0     110      0.15    1    1     2     0` output is different from expected.

Comment: seems that this might give wrong result if `velocity` is constant, due to `cumcount`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

As the question describe, we should count when there is a change, I suggest the following solution:

```
data = {'exercise': ['squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench'],
        'session': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'weight': [100, 100, 120, 120, 80, 80, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 80, 90, 100, 110],
        'velocity': [0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15],
        'set': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
        'rep': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = data.keys())


# df['velocity'] = 0.30
# df['weight'] = 100
# print(df)

grp_rep = ['exercise', 'session',  'weight']
grp_set = ['exercise','session']
def is_diff(arr):
    return [0] + [int(d) for d in arr[:-1]!=arr[1:]]
    
df['rep_sol'] = df.groupby(grp_rep)['velocity'].transform(lambda x: is_diff(x.values))
df['set_sol'] = df.groupby(grp_set)['weight'].transform(lambda x: is_diff(x.values))
df['rep_sol'] = df.groupby(grp_rep)['rep_sol'].cumsum().astype(int)
df['set_sol'] = df.groupby(grp_set)['set_sol'].cumsum().astype(int)
cols = ['exercise', 'session',  'weight', 'velocity', 'set', 'set_sol', 'rep', 'rep_sol']
print(df[cols])
```

which return:

```
   exercise  session  weight  velocity  set  set_sol  rep  rep_sol
0     squat        0     100      0.30    0        0    0        0
1     squat        0     100      0.25    0        0    1        1
2     squat        0     120      0.20    1        1    0        0
3     squat        0     120      0.15    1        1    1        1
4     bench        0      80      0.30    0        0    0        0
5     bench        0      80      0.25    0        0    1        1
6     bench        0     100      0.20    1        1    0        0
7     bench        0     110      0.15    1        2    1        0
8     squat        1     120      0.30    0        0    0        0
9     squat        1     130      0.25    1        1    0        0
10    squat        1     140      0.20    2        2    0        0
11    squat        1     150      0.15    3        3    0        0
12    bench        1      80      0.30    0        0    0        0
13    bench        1      90      0.25    1        1    0        0
14    bench        1     100      0.20    2        2    0        0
15    bench        1     110      0.15    3        3    0        0
```

This solution still hold if we test for `weight`and `velocity`constant.

```
data = {'exercise': ['squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'squat', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench', 'bench'],
        'session': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        'weight': [100, 100, 120, 120, 80, 80, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 80, 90, 100, 110],
        'velocity': [0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15, 0.30, 0.25, 0.20, 0.15],
        'set': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
        'rep': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = data.keys())

df['velocity'] = 0.30
df['weight'] = 100
# print(df)

grp_rep = ['exercise', 'session',  'weight']
grp_set = ['exercise','session']
def is_diff(arr):
    return [0] + [int(d) for d in arr[:-1]!=arr[1:]]
    
df['rep_sol'] = df.groupby(grp_rep)['velocity'].transform(lambda x: is_diff(x.values))
df['set_sol'] = df.groupby(grp_set)['weight'].transform(lambda x: is_diff(x.values))
df['rep_sol'] = df.groupby(grp_rep)['rep_sol'].cumsum().astype(int)
df['set_sol'] = df.groupby(grp_set)['set_sol'].cumsum().astype(int)
#cols = ['exercise', 'session',  'weight', 'velocity', 'set', 'set_sol', 'rep', 'rep_sol']
cols = ['exercise', 'session',  'weight', 'velocity', 'set_sol', 'rep_sol']
print(df[cols])
```

which will return no changes as what should be expected:

```
   exercise  session  weight  velocity  set_sol  rep_sol
0     squat        0     100       0.3        0        0
1     squat        0     100       0.3        0        0
2     squat        0     100       0.3        0        0
3     squat        0     100       0.3        0        0
4     bench        0     100       0.3        0        0
5     bench        0     100       0.3        0        0
6     bench        0     100       0.3        0        0
7     bench        0     100       0.3        0        0
8     squat        1     100       0.3        0        0
9     squat        1     100       0.3        0        0
10    squat        1     100       0.3        0        0
11    squat        1     100       0.3        0        0
12    bench        1     100       0.3        0        0
13    bench        1     100       0.3        0        0
14    bench        1     100       0.3        0        0
15    bench        1     100       0.3        0        0
```

Comment: Actually, in this case I would have expected the sets to increase by one and reset when the session or exercise value changes. But that wasn’t part of my example, didn’t think of this scenario when I created my example.

Comment: Is this solve your question? You are welcome to open a new one with new expected senarios. Kr.